# If/Else Statements, and unintended String Concatenation

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, ecmascript-6

novice programmer here.

I'm currently working on a project that pumps integers into a text field, yet decided to run the array through a for loop which shoves each item into a string that's more presentable for the user. The for loop, however, is displaying this in the console.log:

```
2 + 1 + 4 + 1 +
```

Bit of clarification - it's a dice roller. The for loop segment of this click event is below, and I don't know how to specify to concatenate the last array item to not include a "+" but a "=" instead.

```
let diceString = '';
for (let i = 0; i <= d4Array.length; i++) {
  if(i == d4Array.length) {
    diceString += d4Array[i] + ' =';
    break; 
  }
  else {
    diceString += d4Array[i] + ' + ';
  }
  console.log(diceString);   
}
```

Comment: `(i == d4Array.length)` will NEVER be true inside that for loop ... `i == d4Array.length - 1` will be true in the last iteration

Comment: i == d4Array.length - 1 is now omitting the final dice result in the log

Comment: How d4Array looks like, sample data of that please

Comment: d4Array starts as an empty array, click events push dice results into it.

Comment: you've gone and changed `i < d4Array.length` to `i <= d4Array.length` ... why? did anyone tell you that an array of length n has elements 0 to n? no ... an array of length n has elements 0 to n-1 - as always

Comment: Yeah it would make more sense to have (i = 0; i < d4Array.length; i++) - You have a boundary error on your loop

Comment: i guess you should use a "join" instead of a loop to do this and manually add the last element.

Comment: i edited the code snippet to show my initial 'for loop'.

Comment: if `i == d4Array.length`, then `d4Array[i]` will always be an out of bounds exception, as arrays are offset based (start at 0)

Comment: @Tuckbros I tried to use .join but for the sake of presentation I wanted to add a "+" between dice results to make it easier for the user to make sense of it

Comment: @goon Then why not `d4Array.join( ' + ' )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop iterates over 5 items in your old code. `d4Array.length` will be 4, but since the index starts at 0 it will iterate over 5 items before i reaches 4 ( 0,1,2,3,4 ). That is why your last item returns undefined. You can fix this by replacing `let i = 0; i <= d4Array.length; i++` with `let i = 0; i < d4Array.length; i++`.

To select the last item `i` would have to be the length of the array minus one for the same reason. Thus turn `i === d4Array.length` into `i === d4Array.length - 1`

```js
d4Array = [2,1,4,1];

let diceString = '';
for (let i = 0; i < d4Array.length; i++) {
  if(i === d4Array.length - 1 )
    diceString += d4Array[i] + ' =';
  else
    diceString += d4Array[i] + ' + ';

  console.log(diceString);   
}
```

Comment: @goon No prob. This would normally be done with a reduce method. It may be interesting to look into: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce Bookmark the MDN website by the way it is an excellent resource. If you are just learning js I recommend https://javascript.info/ which is also excellent and free. ;)